# Search within a user's QAs and bookmarks at once

Tags: support, search, search-box

Currently, to search within a user's QAs, we can use `user:<userId>`, and to search within a user's bookmarks, we can use `inbookmarks:<userId>`.

Those were two search criteria, but if I want to search within both QAs and bookmarks, as far as I know, there's no way to do that, would be great to have this search capability.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking to limit searching to the realm of questions that a user has bookmarked OR questions that a user has asked or answered. Correct? I think if you combine those search terms it does an AND, which isn't particularly helpful, IMO.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's correct, but why will it be `AND`?

Comment: @WenfangDu because most search operators are ANDed. Each term you add refines the search more. IIRC, only the actual `or` will do an OR (unsurprisingly) but the `or` operator *only* works with tags, not with other search terms.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, "the `or` operator _only_ works with tags" is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Many times I've complaint but here it is again: the on-site search is not very good for finding things you *need*. It's exceptional for finding things you already know of. Any small variation e.g., "search" instead of "searching" and you won't find the thing you need.

Comment: @VLAZ SE has always said to use actual search engines, like google. That's why they worry so much about good SEO.